# On css: if text line is break show dots

Tags: css

I seen before this solution but i not remember where exactly... without JS

maybe it's work when line is break.
But what a css property is?

**Question is:**
how to show for user: **dots**, if text longer than 150px

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5UPRU/2)

```css
div {
  font-family: Arial;
  background: #99DA5E;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 1%;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 17px;
  color: #252525;
}
```

```html
<div>apple</div>
<div>jack fruit</div>
<div>super puper long title for fruit</div>
<div>watermelon</div>
```

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Are you talking about an ellipsis? Add this to your CSS

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5UPRU/7/

Comment: Don't forget the normal 'overflow: hidden' bit for this to become active. http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/textoverflow.html

Comment: Your fiddle is also not showing the correct output. look at third div's content

Answer (score 21):

In order for `text-overflow: ellipsis` to work you must also specify a `width` (or a `max-width`), `white-space: nowrap` and `overflow: hidden`

The element must be a block so make sure to use `display: block` or `display: inline-block` on inline elements.

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You're looking for [`text-overflow: ellipsis;`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/#text-overflow0) - you need to specify it on the `<div>` in addition to `white-space: nowrap;` and `overflow: hidden;`

```
div {
    font-family: Arial;
    background: #99DA5E;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 1%;
    width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 17px;
    color: #252525;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5UPRU/4/

Answer (score 4):

You can use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` in css file. for example:

```css
div {
font-family: Arial;
background: #99DA5E;
margin: 5px 0;
padding: 1%;
width: 150px;
overflow: hidden;
height: 17px;
color: #252525;
}
span {
float: left;
font-family: Arial;
background: #FAFA41;
margin: 5px 0;
padding: 1%;
width: 150px;
overflow: hidden;
height: 17px;
color: #505050;
}

.short-text {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>apple</div>
<div>jack fruit</div>
<div class="short-text">super puper long title for fruit</div>
<div>watermelon</div>


<span class="short-text">should look like this...</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.ellipsis-container {
  width: 173px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left !important;
  display: block;
}

.ellipsis-container span {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
}

<div class="ellipsis-container">
    <span>Your text goes here</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, it's better to explain how this can address the question