# how I implement break within angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

```
<div ng-init="mem=false" ng-hide='mem'>
            <p ng-init="mms=true" style="padding-top:1em;"><b>Membership:</b></p>
            <!-- // Edited By Soumyadeep on 14/05/2016 -->
            <p>
                <!-- <input type="text" id="edu" style="border:none" readonly="readonly"> -->

               {{membership|cut:mms:false:100:'...'}}

                <span ng-hide="membership.length<=100?true:false"><a ng-click="mms= !mms" style='float:right'><b>{{!mms?'less':'more'}}</b></a></span>
            </p>
        </div>
```

In this portion I have to include break after ending of every membership. I also used  white-space:pre-wrap but it is not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868503/on-css-if-text-line-is-break-show-dots

Comment: what do you mean by ending of every membership?

Comment: membership is an array.. I want to use break end of every array element

Comment: what is the value of membership ?

Comment: why dont you use ng-repeat for array ?

Comment: I have edited the code section. please check it

Comment: what is the filter cut ? what does it do?  did you try the answer below ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do, but just as a tip. on the ng-hide just put ng-hide="membership.length<=100".

Comment: cut is a function. it is used to cut the text after the length exceeds 100

Comment: I have tried the answer below. It is not working

Comment: could you edit the post and provide the value of membership ? or a screenshot of how it is currently rendering.

Comment: Are you tried something like this filter http://plnkr.co/edit/SJproV3KjYkrxgnHQqXs?p=preview ?