# table row expanding with text

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

how do i make table rows to be of the exactly same height? whenever the text in the `<td>` exceeds the limit it exand the row. How do i make it in a way that it don't do that. instead show less text 
 here is the code

```
<div class="firstDiv" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">

    <table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr style="height: 20px;">
            <th width="33%">First Name</th>
            <th width="33%">Last Name</th>
            <th width="33%">Country Of Origin OR MIG</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Hopkins lee brimlow</td>
            <td>Not living in world right now</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: get td text length and compare it with some value like 50 0r 60 character and then remove rest and show `...` instead of it

Comment: Is this the only way, can't i use css some how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868503/on-css-if-text-line-is-break-show-dots

Comment: You can give fixed height and then use `text-overflow: ellipsis` and `overflow: hidden`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the text around a div

```
<div class="firstDiv" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">

    <table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr style="height: 20px;">
            <th width="33%"><div>
            First Name
            </div></th>
            <th width="33%"><div>
            Last Name
            </div></th>
            <th width="33%"><div>
            Country Of Origin OR MIG
            </div></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div>
            Mark
            </div></td>
            <td><div>
            Hopkins lee brimlow
            </div></td>
            <td><div>
            Not living in world right now
            </div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And use height

```
th div, td div{
  height:40px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L2awyezb/

Answer (score 1):

As regards multiple related content sections (vis-a-vis table cells) and a concise, "well-manicured" UI, you must have well-formed data or be willing to compromise.  Per your question, the implicit assumption is that your data is *not* well-formed (in the amount-of-text sense) and you are therefore willing to compromise.  Two suggestions:

- [Disallow white space wrapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):

  ```
  td { white-space: nowrap; }
  ```
- [Enforce a max-width and make an ellipsis](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/):

  ```
  td {
      white-space: nowrap;
      max-width: 67px;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
  ```

The key with both of these suggestions is that they lock the height of each `td` element (and thereby the entire row) to a single text line via the `white-space: nowrap`.

There are of course other options for a consistent table height, but it's difficult to enumerate them all without a more explicit question.